# Add a point after the last point in a path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

Is there a way in Inkscape to add a new point after the last of before the first point of an open path (i.e. a path where there's no connection between the first and last point)?

I only have found ways to add a new point on an existing line between two points, but in this case, this would mean adding a new point before the last point, moving the last point out of the way and adjusting the new point and it's Bézier guide until it somewhat matches the original point at that position. Is there a better way to extend a path with a new point?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's very simple.

Assuming that you have an open path:

[image: Existing open path]

You have just to **select it before using [pencil or bezier tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html)**. When the mouse is over an open node, it is highlighted in red and you can **click and drag to continue the path** (see the hint):

[image: you can continue the path]

Comment: This doesn't work for me - it allows me to move the selected node, but not to add a new node after the selected node.

Comment: What is your version of Inkscape? And the OS?

Comment: This works also for version 1.0.1 (2020-09-07).
If the path has not been selected previously, there is a message `with shift to append to selected path`, but that does not work for me.

Comment: Also not working for me.  Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @LibrarySeph What is your version of Inkscape? And the OS?

Comment: I added a new answer based off the issue I was running into.  I had a closed shape, even though the stroke did not create a closed shape.

Answer (score 4):

I did not find [Paolo's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/26029/56552) to work in my version of Inkscape, running on Ubuntu 17.10: Inkscape 0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06).

I found two places in the online documentation. One of which I could not manage to get working (user error?), and one I could, which is the one I'm using now:

1. https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html#idm2234 **Delete, create, duplicate --> <kbd>SHIFT+D</kbd> Duplicate selected node(s)** -- **Did** work for me.
2. https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html#idm1874 **Move nodes (mouse) --> <kbd>Left-Mouse+Drag+Space</kbd> Drop a copy**  -- Did **not** work for me.

---

[image: Annotated 0.92 Inkscape documentation]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the shape is closed, even though it doesn't seem like it.

Select two end points and choose "Break Apart Path at Selected Nodes" [image]